# How many objects are created in this code?

Tags: java, object

```
SurveyData newSurvey = new SurveyData(2);
SurveyData oldSurvey = new SurveyData();
SurveyData currentSurvey = oldSurvey;
oldSurvey = new SurveyData(5);       
newSurvey.setAges(0,45);
newSurvey.printAges();
```

Comment: It depends on the content of the two constructors and the two methods.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `SurveyData`'s constructor and the other methods called on these objects don't create additional objects in them, the answer is three. Every call to the `new` operator creates a new object. Assigning `SurveyData currentSurvey = oldSurvey` does **not** create a new object, even though it's a new variable declaration.

Answer (score 3):

```
SurveyData newSurvey = new SurveyData(2);
```

this line crates a new object, and `newSurvey` reference points an object.

```
SurveyData oldSurvey = new SurveyData();
```

this line crates a new object, and `oldSurvey` reference points an object.

```
SurveyData currentSurvey = oldSurvey;
```

this line does not create an object. currentSurvey reference points the same object which oldSurvey points.

```
oldSurvey = new SurveyData(5);
```

this line create a new object. Anymore oldSurvey reference points this new object.

You can see this process in the below image.

[image: I changed]